# ActiveRecord not recognising belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have teacher and student models, where a student `belongs_to :teacher, optional: true` and teacher `has_many :students`

In the rails console, when I try `Teacher.find(11).students` it returns the students for the 11th teacher (as expected)

However, when I try `Student.find(3).teachers` it returns an error:
`NoMethodError (undefined method 'teachers' for #<Student..>)`

Note: the 11th teacher and 3rd student exist and have records in their associated tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Student `belongs_to :teacher`, so it should be

```
Student.find(3).teacher
```

Note singular form for `teacher`